# SQL Server : how can use innerjoin with distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need voter count;

```
SELECT voter, COUNT(voter) as numvoters
FROM TxVotes
WHERE timestamp >= '2017-07-22' AND
      timestamp < '2017-07-23'
GROUP BY voter
ORDER BY COUNT(voter) DESC
```

inner join with DISTINCT (Add DISTINCT author)

```
SELECT v.voter, COUNT(v.voter) as numvoters
FROM TxVotes v JOIN
     Comments c
     ON v.voter = DISTINCT c.author 
WHERE v.timestamp >= '2017-07-21' AND
      v.timestamp < '2017-07-22' AND
      c.body LIKE '"ko"'
GROUP BY v.voter
ORDER BY COUNT(v.voter);
```

But it's not working...

How can I use inner join with distinct?

Comment: I think sample data and desired results would really clarify what you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be done like this

```
SELECT v.voter, COUNT(v.voter) as numvoters
FROM TxVotes v JOIN
     (select DISTINCT c.author from  Comments c where c.body LIKE '"ko"') c
     ON v.voter = c.author
WHERE v.timestamp >= '2017-07-21' AND
      v.timestamp < '2017-07-22' 
GROUP BY v.voter
ORDER BY COUNT(v.voter);
```

But I prefer to do this using `Exists`

```
SELECT v.voter, COUNT(v.voter) as numvoters
FROM TxVotes v 
WHERE v.timestamp >= '2017-07-21' AND
      v.timestamp < '2017-07-22' AND 
      Exists (select 1 from Comments c where c.body LIKE '"ko"' and v.voter = c.author)
GROUP BY v.voter
ORDER BY numvoters;
```